# Type issue passing `this` as an argument to an overloaded method

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, interface, overloading

I am running into some strange behaviour calling an overloaded virtual method in an inheritance chain that extends a view that ultimately holds a WPF Window class.
The overloaded method takes a more derived interface as an argument, but instead the call seems to made the the method that takes the lesser derived interface argument.

Below is the relevant part of the inheritance chain for the view, where I would expect the overridden method that takes an IWpfWindow as an argument the be called:

```
public class EmbeddedBrowserWpfView : WpfView
{
    protected IEmbeddedWpfBrowser Browser { get; }
    protected IEmbeddedWpfBrowserFactory BrowserFactory { get; }

    protected EmbeddedBrowserWpfView(IEmbeddedWpfBrowserFactory browserFactory) : base()
    {
        this.BrowserFactory = browserFactory;
        this.Browser = BrowserFactory.Create();
    }

    public override IDisposable RegisterWindow(IWpfWindow window)
    {
        var unsubscriber = base.RegisterWindow(window);

        window.AddRootElement(Browser.Element);

        return unsubscriber;
    }
}

public class WpfView : ViewBase, IWpfView
{
    protected new ICollection<IWpfWindow> Windows { get; }

    public WpfView() : base()
    {
        this.Windows = new List<IWpfWindow>();
    }

    public virtual IDisposable RegisterWindow(IWpfWindow window)
    {
        // Check whether view is already registered. If not, add it
        if (!Windows.Contains(window))
        {
            Windows.Add(window);
        }

        return new SimpleUnsubscriber<IWpfWindow>(Windows, window);
    }
}

public abstract class ViewBase : IView
{
    protected ICollection<IWindow> Windows { get; }

    protected ViewBase()
    {
        this.Windows = new List<IWindow>();
    }

    public virtual IDisposable RegisterWindow(IWindow window)
    {
        // Check whether view is already registered. If not, add it
        if (!Windows.Contains(window))
        {
            Windows.Add(window);
        }

        return new SimpleUnsubscriber<IWindow>(Windows, window);
    }
}
```

The method I expect to be called is RegisterWindow(IWpfWindow window) in the EmbeddedBrowserWpfView class.
Instead the RegisterWindow(IWindow window) from the ViewBase class is called from the Window that wants to register with it.

This class too inherits, ultimately from the WPF window class, code below:

```
public class FullScreenWpfWindow : WpfWindow, IWpfWindow
{
    public FullScreenWpfWindow(IView view) : base(view)
    {
    }
}

public partial class WpfWindow : Window, IWpfWindow
{
    protected IView View { get; }

    public WpfWindow(IView view)
    {
        this.View = view;

        InitializeComponent();

        View.RegisterWindow(this);
    }

    public void AddRootElement(UIElement element)
    {
        RootGrid.Children.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Now this class implements the IWpfWindow interface, which in turn does extends the IWindow interface:

```
public interface IWpfWindow : IWindow
{
    void AddRootElement(UIElement element);
}

public interface IWindow
{
}
```

Still, I would have expected the class to regard itself as an IWpfWindow first when passing it as this. Note that even casting it to an IWpfWindow before passing it to View.RegisterWindow(this) does not change the bevaviour.

Could anyone perhaps shed any light on this or how I can get it to call the overloaded method?

Comment: _"I am running into some strange behavior"_ -- in programming, "strange behavior" is almost always really "normal behavior that doesn't fit my misconceptions".

Comment: I think the main reason people come to stackoverflow is to clear up their misconceptions, rather than prove their computer is acting irrational. Thanks for the insght!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example lacks the `IView` interface declaration. But, assuming that interface has only the `void RegisterWindow(IWindow)` overload, the behavior you describe makes perfect sense. The `View` property has type `IView`. The call `View.RegisterWindow(this)` has only the `void RegisterWindow(IWindow)` overload to choose from to call with `this`. So that's what you get.

Frankly, the whole design looks broken to me; multiple implementations of `RegisterWindow()` in multiple interfaces is just asking for exactly the kind of confusion you're having right now.

> how I can get it to call the overloaded method?

You would have to cast `View` to an appropriate type.

Your question lacks the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would allow anyone to actually *know* what the right solution is, but in this case it seems likely that you'd want to cast `View` to `IWpfView` for the purpose of the call. Even better, just declare `View` as `IWpfView View { get; }` so it's already the type you wanted. Since the declaring type is `WpfWindow`, it seems reasonable the type could be `IWpfView`.

Bottom line: this has **nothing** to do with the type of this in the call, and **everything** to do with the type of `View` in the call. The compiler is picking the only overload available to it.

Comment: You're correct, what I didn't manage to see was that I was passing the wrong view. The WpfWindow was supposed to take an IWpfView as argument, that did expose the correct method.  
I'm not happy with the general design either though, and think I will be adding generic types to avoid the multitude of Windows lists and RegisterWindow() implementations. Thank you for the insight!